# Как получить адрес kernel32.dll

Tags: c++, windows, x86

Как получить адрес kernel32.dll не используя функции WinAPI?

Распространенный способ - это

```
auto hKernel32 = *(HMODULE*)(*(DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)(__readfsdword(0x30) + 0x0C) + 0x14))) + 0x10);
```

Здесь берется второй элемент [списка `InLoadOrderModuleList`](https://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Structures/PEB_LDR_DATA.html). Считается, что kernel32 всегда грузится второй (первой грузится ntdll).
Однако это не выглядит надежным, как написать лучше?

Comment: Это будет самоответ, я надеюсь? :)

Comment: @alexolut нормальный вопрос, только ответ слишком очевидный...

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, например

```
HMODULE FindKernel32Base() {
  auto teb = (PTEB)__readfsdword(0x18);
  auto link = teb->ProcessEnvironmentBlock->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;
  for (;;) {
    auto entry = PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY((char*)link - offsetof(LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks));
    auto expected = "kernel32.dll";
    auto name = entry->FullDllName.Buffer + entry->FullDllName.Length / 2 - strlen(expected);
    while ((*name++ | 32) == *expected++ && *expected);  // strcasecmp
    if (*expected == '\0') {
      return (HMODULE)entry->DllBase;
    }
    link = entry->InMemoryOrderLinks.Flink;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вместо того, чтобы полагаться на индекс, следует сделать полноценный поиск по InLoadOrderModuleList. Поле FullDllName в LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY содержит имя модуля. Вместо всяких strcmp достаточно сравнить 1-2 DWORD'а.

Comment: @Abyx Да, полное имя. Да, нужно искать длину строки, не учитывать регистр, но так делают чуть ли не чаще, чем поиском по индексу.

Comment: @Abyx Ждем ответа лучше, да еще и с использованием другого способа. А пока его нет - и этот сойдет, потому что лучше два "так-себе" способа, чем один из вопроса.